# How to add the for loop inside the canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have some code in a graph and I already tried this code in canvas but for loop condition based in this code x&y value ellipse shape draw the canvas.

I want to how to add the for loop inside the canvas and plot the ellipse shape.

```css
#mycanvas{
    position:absolute;
    width:250px;
    height:400px;
    top:200px;
    left:200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet"type="text/css" href="newellipse.css">
    <script src="jfile/myquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<input id="ipvalue" type="text" value="25x^2+4y^2+100x-40y=-100">
<button onclick="checkFruit()">solve</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo1"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>
<p id="demo3"></p>
<p id="demo4"></p>

<canvas id="myCanvas"width="578" height="400" style="position:absolute;left:220px;top:50px";>
<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var step = 2*Math.PI/20;  // see note 1
var h = 150; 
var k = 150;
var r = 80;

ctx.beginPath();  //tell canvas to start a set of lines

for(var theta=0;  theta < 2*Math.PI;  theta+=step) {
    var x = h +       r*Math.cos(theta) ;
    var y = k - 0.5 * r*Math.sin(theta) ;  //note 2.
    ctx.lineTo(x,y);
}

ctx.closePath();     //close the end to the start point
ctx.stroke();        //actually draw the accumulated lines

function checkFruit() {
    var reg =/([\-+])?\s*(\d+)?([a-zA-Z])\b/g;
 
    var equation = id("ipvalue").val();
    var spli = reg.exec(equation);
    alert(spli);
    var y = document.getElementById("ipvalue").value;

    switch(y) {
        case "25x^2+4y^2+100x-40y=-100":
            text = "Formula for Ellipse x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2=1";
            text1= "First RHS side value consider for 1";
            text2= "LHS side divide by RHS value for 16";
            text3= "Take a square root of denaminater value";
            text4= "Find the x and y value";
   
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
            document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = text1;
            document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = text2;
            document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = text3;
            document.getElementById("demo4").innerHTML = text4;
            break;
    // add the default keyword here
    }
}
</script>
</body>
<html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
        zoomEnabled: true,
        title:{
            text: "Try Zooming And Panning"
        },
        axisY:{
            includeZero: false
        },
        title: {
            text: "Graph"
        },
        data: [{        
            type: "spline",
            dataPoints: [
                { x:-15, y:0 },
                { x:-10, y:18 },
                { x:0, y:20 },
                { x:10, y:18 },
                { x:15, y:0 },
                { x:10, y:-18 },
                { x:0, y:-20 },
                { x:-10, y:-15 },
                { x:-15, y:0 },
            ]},
        ]
    });
    chart.render();
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="correct"style="position:absolute;width:500px;height:70%;top:80px;left:250px;">
    <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 400px; width: 100%;">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In that modal how to x and y value inside the for loop condition base draw the ellipse graph?

Comment: You titled **How to add the for loop...** but I now see bunch of code. Are they from the same file? Obviously, no: but please name your files. And I hope <script src="jfile/myquery.js"></script> is not required.

Comment: ya its my own js file its not required.

Comment: CanvasJS is a **charting app** ... You're trying to make a charting app do the job of a **graphing app**. You're setting yourself up for failure.

Answer (score 0):

<canvas> must be closed as shown [here](http://devdocs.io/html/element/canvas).

The `style` attribute on <canvas> must have semicolon (`;`) before double-quote (`"`).
`html
<canvas id="myCanvas"width="578" height="400" style="position:absolute;left:220px;top:50px;"></canvas>`

I personally prefer `document.querySelector(...)` over `document.getElementById(...)`.

I took liberty to increase the number of lines for ellipsis from `20` to `1000`.

My console says `ReferenceError: id is not defined`. So instead use `document.querySelector('#ipvalue')`.

Also note that `.val(...)` works but with [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/val/). And html uses `.value` property. So, the code become `document.querySelector('#ipvalue').value`.

I touched deliberately at your code structure... (I mean the `checkFruit(...)` function)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <!--<link rel="stylesheet"type="text/css" href="newellipse.css">
        <script src="jfile/myquery.js"></script>-->
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="ipvalue" type="text" value="25x^2+4y^2+100x-40y=-100">
        <button onclick="checkFruit()">solve</button>

        <p id="demo"></p>
        <p id="demo1"></p>
        <p id="demo2"></p>
        <p id="demo3"></p>
        <p id="demo4"></p>
        <canvas id="myCanvas"width="578" height="400" style="position:absolute;left:220px;top:50px;"></canvas>
        <script>
            var canvas = document.querySelector("#myCanvas");
            var context2d = canvas.getContext("2d");

            var step = 2*Math.PI/1000;  // see note 1
            var h = 150;
            var k = 150;
            var r = 80;

            context2d.beginPath();  //tell canvas to start a set of lines

            for(var theta = 0;  theta < 2*Math.PI;  theta += step)
            {
                var x = h +       r*Math.cos(theta);
                var y = k - 0.5 * r*Math.sin(theta);  //note 2.
                context2d.lineTo(x,y);
            }

            context2d.closePath();     //close the end to the start point
            context2d.stroke();        //actually draw the accumulated lines







            var splitter = /([\-+])?\s*(\d+)?([a-zA-Z])\b/g;
            var source = document.querySelector('#ipvalue');

            var target = document.querySelector("#demo");
            var target1 = document.querySelector("#demo1");
            var target2 = document.querySelector("#demo2");
            var target3 = document.querySelector("#demo3");
            var target4 = document.querySelector("#demo4");

            function checkFruit()
            {
                var equation = splitter.exec(source.value);

                console.log('SOURCE: ', source.value);
                console.log('EQUATION: ', equation);
                console.log('SUGGESTION: ', source.value.match(splitter));

                var y = source.value;

                switch(y)
                {
                    case "25x^2+4y^2+100x-40y=-100":
                        var text = "Formula for Ellipse x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2=1";
                        var text1 = "First RHS side value consider for 1";
                        var text2 = "LHS side divide by RHS value for 16";
                        var text3 = "Take a square root of denaminater value";
                        var text4 = "Find the x and y value";

                        target.innerHTML = text;
                        target1.innerHTML = text1;
                        target2.innerHTML = text2;
                        target3.innerHTML = text3;
                        target4.innerHTML = text4;
                        break;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
<html>
```

Comment: Semi-colon was after style attribute. This way `<canvas...style="...stuff...";>` instead of `<canvas...style="...stuff...;">`

This was just a note. Not the reason of any error.

Comment: Ah ok I thought you advised to do so.